# Observers: should I use values passed to the function, or can I use this.value safely instead?

Tags: polymer, web-component, observers

I have code like this in my app:

```
  observers: [
    '_dataGenericObserver(userData.generic)',
  ],

  // If this.userData.generic.id is set, then the register tab is
  // NOT visible. In this case, the selected tab mustn't be "register"...
  _dataGenericObserver: function(){
    if (this.userData.generic.id){
      this.selected = 'login';
    } else {
      if (this.defaultRegister) {
        this.selected = 'register';
      } else {
        this.selected = 'login';
      }
    }
  },
```

Is this safe? Or should I *always* do this instead:

```
  observers: [
    '_dataGenericObserver(userData.generic)',
  ],

  // If this.userData.generic.id is set, then the register tab is
  // NOT visible. In this case, the selected tab mustn't be "register"...
  _dataGenericObserver: function(generic){
    if (generic.id){
      this.selected = 'login';
    } else {
      if (this.defaultRegister) {
        this.selected = 'register';
      } else {
        this.selected = 'login';
      }
    }
  },
```

...?
I noticed in some cases in other parts of the app that if I have an observer on `_someFunc(value.subvalue)`, and then have `_someFunc: function( subValue)`, in the function `subValue` is set, whereas `this.value.subValue` isn't. However, I am not able to replicate it - sorry.

Questions:

- Is it always recommended to use the values passed to the functions, rather than `this.*`?
- WHEN is it likely to happen, that a `subValue` is set as a function parameter, but NOT in `this.value.subValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you should always explicitly declare and use the dependencies that you want to access in a observer instead of using `this` because as you experienced `this.myVar` might not be set while the `myVar` parameter of the observer function is.

At least this was the official [response](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4028#issuecomment-251746563) from Polymer developers.(there might be some more [issues](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+this+observer+dependencies+is%3Aopen) regarding this)

This applies to Polymer 1.x not sure if this is different for Polymer 2.x